# Looking for Math Font to match IBM Plex Serif / Sans

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

## The Question

Hi, I've recently decided to switch over to IBM Plex, and while computer modern is very nice, it doesn't go too well with Plex it seems, and I'm not sure what I can do with regards to maths fonts.

*Edit: I'm using pdfLaTeX*

I'm looking for either good alternatives from people who have seen / know more than me, **and / or** some way of finding out what's available. (Most of my google searches have returned results comparing `\mathrm` etc.)

## Demos

> ### Plex Serif
>
> [image]
>
> ### Plex Sans
>
> [image]

Comment: You are using Overleaf, aren't you? And are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: If you have used `\setmainfont` to set your main body font, I suggest using `\setmathfont` to set your math font.

Comment: You may get some inspiration here: http://jf.burnol.free.fr/showcase.html#frclog

Comment: Ahh. I definitely forgot an important detail - I'm using pdfLaTeX, so I'm looking at packages not just fonts.

Comment: @Ross thanks for showing that! That makes it a lot better. If you put that as an answer I'll happily mark it as 'correct'

Comment: @Ross Thank you very much for the link... I couldn't even think that there existed such a link before.

Comment: According to this GitHub comment, "a version of Plex with full mathematical glyphs" will be designed in 2019. https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues/122#issuecomment-358501485

Comment: I've seen, I'm just not planning on waiting that long :P

Comment: It’s been only a few years, but Plex Math is in public alpha now: https://github.com/IBM/plex/issues/250#issuecomment-1834127281

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @Ross showing me `mathastext` I reckon I've got a working solution.

## Solution

#### Math Symbols

```
\usepackage{fourier}
```

In my opinion, fourier's symbols matches better stylistically, however I don't want to keep the font-related changes so I add it first (so that the other font packages overwrite that).

#### Math Font

```
\usepackage{plex-serif}
```

I want to use a serif font for the math, so I add this after `fourier` so that it overwrites it, and before `mathastext` so that it's actually used for the maths

#### Apply the font to math

```
\usepackage[basic,italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
```

`mathastext` seems good, but to me it had a few issues when used without any options.

1. Brackets for matrices, when multiline brackets were required `mathastext` just grabbed the `[]` characters used by the font, and didn't do anything to make them multiline. This was fixed by adding the `basic` option — though this also had the effect of no replacing a few other symbols (a worthwhile price in my mind)
2. Non-italic math by default. This was an easy fix: `italic`
3. Not using the greek letters from the font. Once again easy fix: `symbolgreek`
4. Bad kerning / overlapping (or crammed) letters

To solve the last issue I used another command, seen at the end of this mini-section.

#### Text Font

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{plex-sans}
```

After the serif variant has been set to be used in math by `mathastext` I change to the sans font I want to use for the rest of the document.

#### Spacing Issues

By default, the spacing was the same as italic/slanted text. Which is an issue for math because it can cause overlaps/cramping. To see this in action I drew vertical rules of width `0.1ex` with `\hspace{-0.1ex}` after them, producing
[image: Demo]
For most letters adding 0.5mu of space either side fixed things up, however letters with 'tails' required some extra attention. After some tweaking I managed to get this:
[image: Fixed(sort of)]

While I wouldn't consider this 'fixed' it's better. This is the code used (**sans**):

```
\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0.5mu}{0.5mu}}%
\makeatother

\MTsetmathskips{f}{2.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{g}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{j}{2.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{p}{1.5mu}{0mu}
\MTsetmathskips{y}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{z}{1mu}{0.5mu}
```

And then for the **serif** version:

```
 \makeatletter
 \@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,q,r,t,u,v,w\do{%
 \MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0.5mu}{0.5mu}}%
 \makeatother

 \MTsetmathskips{f}{4.5mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{g}{2.5mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{j}{4mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{p}{2.5mu}{0mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{s}{1mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{x}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{y}{3.5mu}{0.5mu}
 \MTsetmathskips{z}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
```

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

It's minor but it's an improvement

### All together

```
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage[basic,italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{plex-sans}

\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,h,i,k,l,m,n,o,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0.5mu}{0.5mu}}%
\makeatother

\MTsetmathskips{f}{2.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{g}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{j}{2.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{p}{1.5mu}{0mu}
\MTsetmathskips{y}{1.5mu}{0.5mu}
\MTsetmathskips{z}{1mu}{0.5mu}
```

## Result

### Serif

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{plex-sans}
\usepackage[basic,italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
```

[image: Serif]

### Sans

```
\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage[basic,italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
```

[image: Sans]

### Mixed

```
\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage[basic,italic,symbolgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{plex-sans}
```

[image: Mixed]